# Annotating specific dataclass subclass in a signature

Tags: python, generics, typing

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class BaseProduct:
    ...


@dataclass
class ProductA(BaseProduct):
    a_specific_id: int


@dataclass
class ProductSubmissionCommand:
    product_id: str
    product: BaseProduct


class AProductRequestSubmitter:
    def __call__(self, job_id: int, cmd: ProductSubmissionCommand):
        ...
        cmd.product.a_specific_id
```

mypy error is:
`error: "BaseProduct" has no attribute "a_specific_id"`

How to annotate `AProductRequestSubmitter.__call__` properly? This class is specific for `AProduct`, there are other submitters for different product types.

Is it possible to use Generic types or Literal values somehow? Or maybe cast or assert is an only way to go?

Comment: Please build a true [mre]. `a_specific_id` is not a member at all of `ProductSubmissionCommand`...

Comment: You are typehinting `product` as `ProductSubmissionCommand` and in no way does a `ProductSubmissionsCommand` instance has `a_specific_id` attribute. Is that supposed to be `BaseProduct` instead? Or maybe you wanted `product.product.a_specific_id`? Please edit this in the question before we can help you :)

Comment: @rayt yes, you're right, I've edited my post

Comment: @SergeBallesta thanks for suggestion, I've ensured the code is working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 possible ways.

1. Ignore static typint by using an explicit `getattr` call

   ```
    class AProductRequestSubmitter:
        def __call__(self, job_id: int, cmd: ProductSubmissionCommand):
            ...
            getattr(cmd.product, 'a_specific_id')
   ```
2. Use `Generic` to *specialize* `ProductSubmissionCommand` on a static typing point of view:

   ```
    T = TypeVar("T", bound=BaseProduct)


    @dataclass
    class ProductSubmissionCommand(Generic[T]):
        product_id: str
        product: T


    class AProductRequestSubmitter:
        def __call__(self, job_id: int, cmd: ProductSubmissionCommand[ProductA]):
            pass
   ```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you are trying to, I will show the ones that pop out the top of my head right now.

### Ensure correct type at runtime

There may be multiple children having `BaseProduct` as their parent and there is no way for the type checker to know for sure, you will never pass a `ProductSubmissionCommand` instance that has `product` attribute of a type that is a child of `BaseProduct` that does not have `a_specific_id` attribute. In order to make sure this can never happen, you could start your function call with a type assertion, such as:

```py
class AProductRequestSubmitter:
    def __call__(self, job_id: int, cmd: ProductSubmissionCommand):
        if not isinstance(cmd.product, ProductA):
            raise TypeError(f"Only 'ProductA' instances are allowed, not '{cmd.product.__class__.__name__}'")
        ...
        cmd.product.a_specific_id
```

Pycharm (or any other static type checker) should now be quiet, because the program will never reach the part of the code, where `a_specific_id` is accessed unless the correct type is in use.

### Subclass `ProductSubmissionCommand`

If you really plan on using `AProductRequestSubmitter` for instances, where `ProductSubmissionCommand` has `product` of type `ProductA`, you may subclass your `ProductSubmissionCommand` and typehint its `product` attribute as a `ProductA` instance.

```py
@dataclass
class ProductASubmissionCommand(ProductSubmissionCommand):
    product: ProductA


class AProductRequestSubmitter:
    def __call__(self, job_id: int, cmd: ProductASubmissionCommand):
        ...
        cmd.product.a_specific_id
```

Again, all clever typecheckers should now understand, that `cmd` will always have `product.a_specific_id` attribute.

### Use `Protocol`

Using:

```py
class ProductASubmissionCommand(Protocol):
    product: ProductA

class AProductRequestSubmitter:
    def __call__(self, job_id: int, cmd: ProductASubmissionCommand):
        ...
        cmd.product.a_specific_id
```

You are basically saying "accept anything, that has an attribute named `product` of a type `ProductA`". This is a little hacky and makes you create a protocol subclass only for the sake of typehinting this single method call, but, again, should work with all static type checkers.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Checking at runtime is ok, but in the case cmds is an iterable type-checkers won't understand (see: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3497#issuecomment-306401200 for mypy issue). Subclassing is a bit tedious because ProductSumissionCommand is produced by a generic class which does not know which product it produces - proper type is binded by injector module